# Is this knot invariant already treated somewhere in the literature?

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, knot-theory

Fix a knot type $K \subset S^3$, and consider the set $$Y_K = \{ \mbox{Diagrams of }K  \} /  \mbox{planar isotopy}.$$
We can turn $Y_K$ into a metric space by considering the distance induced by Reidemeister moves: 
$d(D_0,D_1) = $ minimum length of a sequence of Reidemeister moves (each move is possibly followed by a planar isotopy), and $D_0,D_1$ are two diagrams
 of $K$.

We can build a graph $\mathcal{G}_K$ as follows: the vertices are given by the points of $Y_K$, while the 
edges are given by the pairs $(D_0,D_1)$ such that $d(D_0,D_1)=1$.

This construction parallels Hirasawa and Yoshiaki's in  "The Gordian Complex of Knots" for
the Gordian metric space of  knots, but unlike the Gordian complex, each vertex of $\mathcal{G}_K$ 
 has only finitely many edges (the number of edges at a vertex $D$ corresponds  to the possible 
inequivalent diagrams - up to planar isotopy - that can be reached from $D$ by a single 
Reidemeister move).

For each knot $K$ we can thus define a function $$\varphi_K : Y_K \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$$ 
called the *simplicity*, as $\varphi_K (D) = \#\{$edges of $\mathcal{G}_K$ that contain $D$ in their boundary$\}$.

As an example the "standard" diagram of a trefoil [trefoil-1](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/wiki/File%3aTriquetra-Vesica-solid.png) has a lower simplicity
than [trefoil-2](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/w/images/f/f2/3_1_AP.gif) (you need to take into account that the former is 3-symmetric).

Taking the minimum of the simplicity over all diagrams of a knot yields an invariant $\mathcal{S}(K)$.

Is the invariant $\mathcal{S}(K)$, or any possible application/connection, known?

Comment: Possibly stupid question: in the definition of simplicity, what does it mean for an edge to contain  a vertex in its boundary? (What is the boundary of an edge?) At first I thought you just meant the two vertices on which the edge is incident, but then simplicity would be the same as degree.

Comment: I didn't understand your example- the diagrams of trefoil-1 and of trefoil-2 are the same up to reparametrization.

Comment: Well, they're not planar isotopic but they're isotopic on the 2-sphere.

Comment: Other than by knowing a complete set of diagrams for K, is there any way to compute S(K)?

Comment: @NateEldredge you are right, it is the degree, i just didn't know it was called that way.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd My guess is that if a knot type $K$ does not admit any symmetric diagram 
( call a diagram symmetric if it is sent in itself by a $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$ rotation of the 
projection plane ), then you can compute $\mathcal{S}(K)$ by just looking at the diagrams of $K$ that
minimize the crossing number.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd in particular, any diagram with $n$ crossings admits at least $2n$ Reidemeister 1 moves and at least $n+1$ Reidemeister 2 moves so picking any particular diagram of the knot gives you an upper bound on the number of crossings you need to consider (this bound can evidently be improved, I just did the laziest thing).

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole You also need to take in account the possible 
symmetries of  the diagram; for example in the first diagram of the 
trefoil posted above, making a Reidemeister move 1 in any of the "external"
arcs produces the same diagram up to planar isotopy (which in this case is 
just a 120° rotation).

Comment: @DanieleCeloria Yeah, I didn't read carefully enough and was imagining we were talking about the graph where there would be multiple edges for multiple Reidemeister links between the same ambient-isotopic diagrams.

Comment: @DanielMoskovich The point of the example  was that, due to different symmetries in the two diagrams, the number of inequivalent (up to planar isotopy) diagrams 
that can be reached with a single Reidemeister move  from Trefoil1 is less than for Trefoil2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the minimal degree of "Reidemeister complex" has some meaning.

I know one paper about this topic.

[A distance for diagrams of a knot](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2011.11.019)

Comment: Thanks, this paper is really useful, but it actually focuses on prime Reidemeister moves, and doesn't seem to care for planar isotopies, so the invariants defined should be different from $\mahtcal{S}$.